# Generate checksum without opening the file

Tags: c#, cryptography

Is there a way to calculate the checksum of a file that is readonly?

The only examples I have seen uses an algorithm like this

```
public string GetChecksum()
{
    FileStream file = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open);
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
    file.Close();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte t in retVal)
    {
        sb.Append(retVal[1].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Readonly does not mean you cannot open it. Not sure what the question is?

Comment: Err... since you only need to read a file to compute a checksum readonly is just what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a file even if it's readonly.
It is not possible to generate a checksum without opening the file, since you can't read a file without opening it.

You should pass `FileAccess.Read` to open it as read-only.

Also, you should generate checksums using SHA512, not MD5.

Comment: See here an example why MD5 is not good for file checksums: http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/

Comment: also he should use a `using` clause on that FileStream, and consider being explicit by using the `File.OpenRead()` method, rather than the `new FileStream()` constructor.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy.aspx), the FileStream constructor you are using opens the file for read/write. Use an overload that specifies FileAccess.Read.

> The constructor is given read/write
>   access to the file, and it is opened
>   sharing Read access

Comment: Specifically, the constructor call should be `new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot generate a checksum without reading the entire file.

Generally, readonly files can be opened. There might be file or folder permissions that prevent a given user from opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no. You have to read a file to do anything with what's in it. But you're opening with Generic access when you probably want `FileStream(_filePath,FileAccess.Read,true,4096,true);` to open it read-only. StreamReader will do this automatically.